# Spatie Browsershot and letterhead / CSS

Tags: php, css, laravel, google-chrome-headless, browsershot

I'm trying to generate PDF with content of a view in Laravel application using [spatie/browsershot](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot) & [laravel-browsershot wrapper](https://github.com/verumconsilium/laravel-browsershot); I am using svg as my letterhead background and would like to place content of the view in within certain area of the SVG on every page. Unfortunately the margins `->margins(40, 20, 40, 30)` makes my `#watermark` div to shift with the margin - it is not in fixed 0,0 position anymore. 
Could you help me to setup the watermark div correctly please? So it is not affected by page margins

in controller

```
 return PDF::loadView('pdf.letter', compact('letter'))
            ->showBackground()
            ->waitUntilNetworkIdle()
            ->margins(40, 20, 40, 30)
            ->format('A4')
            ->inline();
```

in my blade I setup following css

```
#watermark { 
 position: fixed;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 width: 21cm;
 height: 29.7cm;
 z-index: -1000;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="watermark">
        <img src="{{ asset('/img/a4.svg') }}" height="100%" width="100%" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- The content of PDF here -->
    </div>
</body>
```

The best what I achieved is this

[image: here]

where dash line rectangle is the area in the SVG file where I wish all content of the view, to flow in through all the pages, respecting set margins

I achieved it with removal of `->margins(....)` in php and adding style to the `<body>` tag

```
body {
 margin-top: 4cm;
 margin-right: 2cm;
 margin-bottom: 4cm;
 margin-left: 3cm;
}
```

as you see the margin of the page seems to be 0 on the bottom of the 1st page and on top of next page

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

[Custom Header and Footer - https://github.com/spatie/browsershot#headers-and-footers](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot#headers-and-footers)

```
Browsershot::html($someHtml)
 ->showBrowserHeaderAndFooter()
 ->headerHtml($someHtml)
 ->footerHtml($someHtml)
 ->save('example.pdf');
```

and

[Handle page breaks - https://github.com/spatie/browsershot/issues/333](https://github.com/spatie/browsershot/issues/333)

```
<div style="page-break-after:always;">
```

or

This can be solved with `<div style="page-break-inside: avoid;">`. Just keep in mind the property doesn't work inside `flex`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks Brian, I improved my answer in case the links disappear from the internet (I hate it  when I find an answer to dead links, I totally forgot).

Comment: @TravisHi thank you for the answer, I did not expect my question being noticed after the long time from posting. The ` ->headerHtml($someHtml)` does nothing when I put simple html like `<p>SomeText</p> however if I don't chain `headerHtml` method standard chrome header is printed with the page print date in my case. Could you advice how $someHtml shall be structured to include said image?

Comment: @dascorp for e.g.


~~~
    ->headerHtml('
          <div><p>header</p></div>
    ')

~~~